# How to create a function to hold one block of code and then execute?

Tags: c#

I have two buttons that contain their own functionality (which I have not included in the code snippet below as it is not relevant), but they also contain the same block of text (which is shown in the code snippet below). My question as I am a beginner in C#, is there a way where I can just write the code once and use the function shall I call to be placed in the buttons instead?

Code Snippet:

```
        private void btnAlpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

//Replace Non Alpha code would go here…

/*Count number of lines in processed text,
extra line is always counted so -1 brings it to correct number*/
int numLines = copyText.Split(“/n”).Length - 1;

//seperate certain characters in order to find words
char[] seperator = (" " + nl).ToCharArray();

//number of words, characters and include extra line breaks variable
int numberOfWords = copyText.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
int numberOfChar = copyText.Length - numLines;

//Unprocessed Summary
newSummary = nl + "Word Count: " + numberOfWords + nl + "Characters Count: " + numberOfChar;

        }

private void btnReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

//Replace code would go here…

/*Count number of lines in processed text,
extra line is always counted so -1 brings it to correct number*/
int numLines = copyText.Split(“/n”).Length - 1;

//seperate certain characters in order to find words
char[] seperator = (" " + nl).ToCharArray();

//number of words, characters and include extra line breaks variable
int numberOfWords = copyText.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
int numberOfChar = copyText.Length - numLines;

//Unprocessed Summary
newSummary = nl + "Word Count: " + numberOfWords + nl + "Characters Count: " + numberOfChar;

        }
```

Comment: Put your code in a method?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/36CjZsmszqYmVviLuc8PbbD

Comment: I included my full code in pastebin, I am not sure now that setting a method will work unless I manipulate further due to rest of code in the buttons won't be recognised if I shift the code I mentioned into a separate method: http://paste.ofcode.org/h3ZvTAMkYAnmqfSQY2xnny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you can enclose reusable code in methods (as suggested in comments). If there are parts of the code that behave differently then again you can encapsulate them into a separate methods. Below the code that's repeated in each handler is in `MyMethod`. `btnReplace` specific code is in `MyReplace` and `btnAlpha` specific code is in `MyAlpha`:

```
private void btnReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyReplace();
    MyMethod();
}

private void btnAlpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyAlpha();
    MyMethod();
}

private void MyReplace()
{
    // Replace code
}

private void MyAlpha()
{
    // Alfa code
}

private void MyMethod()
{
    //Replace code would go here…

    /*Count number of lines in processed text,
    extra line is always counted so -1 brings it to correct number*/
    int numLines = copyText.Split(“/n”).Length - 1;

    //seperate certain characters in order to find words
    char[] seperator = (" " + nl).ToCharArray();

    //number of words, characters and include extra line breaks variable
    int numberOfWords = copyText.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    int numberOfChar = copyText.Length - numLines;

    //Unprocessed Summary
    newSummary = nl + "Word Count: " + numberOfWords + nl + "Characters Count: " + numberOfChar;
}
```

If you need some sort of communication between the methods then one option would be to return a value from the first method and pass it into the second one.

Alternatively you can parameterize your main method (if true execute alfa part else execute replace part) and execute it with a parameter saying which part of the code to execute. But if there are many possible alternatives than probably producing separate method for each alternative makes more sense.